# Laravel Relation with serval Table

Tags: laravel

There is my database structure

```
Manpower Table: [
    'manpower_uuid'
    'pwra_uuid'
]

PWRA Table: [
    'pwra_uuid'
    'purchase_order_uuid'
]

purchase Order Table: [
    'purchase_order_uuid',
    'name'
]
```

Question: How can get back the purchase order name when using the manpower record?

```
Reseult: [
    'manpower_uuid'
    'pwra_uuid'
    'purchase_order_uuid'
    'purchase_order.name'
]
```

In ManpowerClass:

I already created the relation

```
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Pwra', 'pwra_uuid', 'pwra_uuid');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PWRA table can be your [pivot table](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) to access your intermediate table. So your Manpower class model would have a `belongsToMany` relationship, and your PWRA class would extend pivot class.

Comment: Do you have any code? Like this: return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\PurchaseOrder', 'pwra', 'purchase_order_uuid', 'pwra_uuid'); ?